# Repeat a column value based on another column value across rows in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

In my Excel sheet, I want Excel to automatically fill in a column value based on the value from the same column in previous rows.

Specifically, consider the following example data:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | abcd | 56.1 | 25 |
| **2** | bcde | 20.0 | 96 |
| **3** | abcd | 75.4 | **`25`** |

The value in **`column C`** of the current row should be automatically filled in with the value from **`column C`** in a previous row where the **`column A`** values match.

Using the example data above, where the current row is **`row 3`**, then **`C3`** should be populated with the value from **`C1`** (25) because **`A3`** matches **`A1`**.

##### Notes

- I may overwrite the formula in some rows;
- There may be multiple matches;
- In the case of multiple matches, the match with the highest row number should be returned;

Is there a way to configure Excel such that it auto-fills column `C` based on matching the value in column `A` to prior rows?

Comment: This will need to use vba in a worksheet_change event.  You cannot have a cell with a formula that the user can ALSO input values.

Comment: To clarify [ScottCraner's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1775139/repeat-a-column-value-based-on-another-column-value-across-rows-in-microsoft-exc#comment2768112_1775139) you *can* "have a cell with a formula that the user can ALSO input values" *however* entering a value would effectively overwrite/delete the formula which may or may not be okay depending on what you are doing.

Comment: Overwriting the formula is fine for me. I can type out a formula in the first row and drag it all the way down. Then, I can type out custom value when required and leave the formula when it is correct. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

###### Formula in C4

```
=IFERROR(
     INDEX($C$1:C3, XMATCH(A4, $A$1:A3,0,-1)),
     "")
```

1. Formula works in both Sheets and Excel;
2. Formula uses XMATCH to return the position of the value in column A where

   - it matches the value in the current row's column A;
   - the row number is less than the current row;
   - rows are searched in reverse order, which will return the result with the highest row number (most recent)
3. Result from XMATCH is used to identify the row to return the value in column C;
4. IFERROR returns a null value where XMATCH errors out (no match);

**Matched Value**
[image]

**Most Recent Matched Value**
[image]

**No Match**
[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. I'll check the edits and approve them (if not applied already).

Comment: NP.  I deleted my comments as no longer relevant.